# Shared folders in 16.04 on a second drive, need to check SHARE FOLDER each day

Tags: 16.04, shared-folders

I´ve set a shared folder under NTFS formatting on a second drive and can access it from windows PCs across the LAN; but each day I start the PC, I have to check again the box SHARE THIS FOLDER, otherwise it would be visible but not accessible from those windows PCs. A second shared folder set in the HOME folder on the main drive doesn´t have this problem, it´s always accesible from outside. Complimentarily, this folder does not show the box SHARE THIS FOLDER checked as one would expect, but it works fine as a shared folder and it´s visible and accesible through the LAN.
Would appreciate any help. My router seems to assign a different IP address each day to this Ubuntu PC, eventually I can fix it if it is of any help.
Best,
Marcelo

Comment: I found out that by openning the folder in mi local Ubuntu PC it becomes available across the network; so it is not necessary to re-check the SHARE THIS FOLDER but simply to open it in the file browser app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use static ip addres. Just edit your /etc/network/interfaces .
For example my.

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static

address 172.16.0.212

netmask 255.255.255.0

gateway 172.16.0.1

Or you can use static DHCP addres. You should set it in your router. It means that router will reserv  special IP address for your network card with MAC address.

Comment: Thanks Yevgeniy, I´ll do it. But I am mostly concerned with the fact that I have to check SHARE FOLDER each day in order to get the sharing functionality, and I don´t think it has to do with the dynamic IP address, because it would affect the other folder located at HOME too, and that folder works ok.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with using NTFS as the file system format. I would propose trying **exfat** instead.

I believe recent versions of Windows supports this format natively, but in Ubuntu, You may need to install the `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` packages first:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```